# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'dict'

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scipy, operators

I wanted to create a permutation test in python, I have a dictionary of observed values, denoted as "a", and a randomly generated values, denoted as "b":

```
  a = {0: 4,1: 3.0,2: 4.0,3: 2.0,4: 3.0,5: 3.0,6: 3.0,7: 3.0,8: 3.0,9: 3.0,10: 2.0
         ,11: 3.0,12: 2.0, 13: 4,14: 2.0,15: 3.0,16: 2.0,17: 2.0,18: 3.0}

     b=[{0: 10,1: 11,2: 10,3: 10.0,4: 10,5: 9,6: 9,7: 10,8: 10,9: 10,10: 9,11: 9.9,12: 9,13: 10,14: 10, 15: 10,  16: 10, 17: 10,18: 10}, {0: 9,1: 9,2: 9,3: 9.0,4: 10,5: 9,6: 9.0,7: 8, 8: 9,9: 10, 10: 9.4,11: 8.44,12: 9.0,13: 8.75,14: 9.4,15: 9.4,16: 8.14,17: 8.88,18: 9.85}]
```

The key-value pair here is that key represents the index of the data points, while value represents any count data, but for example's sake say number of connections.

I wanted to determine a probability under the hypothesis that the observed values in "a" is also random, by this I mean "the connections generated in my observed data are random", using:

```
p_value = (np.sum(b>= a) + np.sum(b <= a)) / 2
```

I tried using operators itemgetter:

```
    from operator import itemgetter
    c = sorted(b,key=itemgetter(0))
    p_value = (np.sum(c>= a) + np.sum(c <= a)) / 2
```

gives an error:
`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'dict'`, I tried using a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    p_value = (np.sum( c[i]>= a) + np.sum(c[i] <= a)) / 2
```

which gives an error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: What is your expected result of `b >= a` and `c[i] >= a`, considering that the operands are lists and dictionaries?

Comment: Why are you using numpy operations on a dictionary structure in the first place? `np.sum()` _et al._ are slower than the python builtins unless you have a numpy array

Comment: b >= a compares each element in the "b" with the observed value in a. It returns a Boolean array of the same size as b, where each element is 1 if b>=a is True, 0 otherwise.

By summing the 1's, I obtain the count of bootstrapped statistics that are as extreme or more extreme than the observed statistic in "a".

I use this to calculate the p-value, which represents the probability of observing a test statistic as extreme as or more extreme than the observed statistic which is "a".

Comment: @Gerard that sounds right if `b` and `a` are arrays, but `b >= a` won't work out of the box like that for dictionaries. You could do something like `sum(b[i][k] >= a[k] for k in b[i].keys() & a.keys())` (assuming that `a` is a single dict and `b` is a list of dicts)